# Python use decorator to implement context manager

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to make two decorators with parameters. `First` creates a `list` with element `x` and calls `func`. `second` is simply calling the `first` by passing a parameter from a dict.

```
def first(x=1):
    def wrapped(func):
        l = [x]
        func(l)
        print(l)
    return wrapped

def second(d={'x':10}):
    return first(x=d['x'])
```

`third` function simply modifies the list passed in.
I want to make any of the four decorators below possible by simply calling `third()`. How should I modify my code?

```
##@second
##@second({'x':100})
##@first
##@first(x=10)
def third(l):
    l.append(-1)

third()
```

For example:

```
## With @first,
## I am expecting to get [1, -1].
## With @first(x=10),
## I am expecting to get [10, -1].
## With @second,
## I am expecting to get [10, -1].
## With @second({x:100}),
## I am expecting to get [100, -1].
```

The upper code is an abstraction of my problem. My real problem is that I want a decorator that handles opening and closing connection for me, so that I only need to write code for handling the connection.

And the connection needs parameters, which is `first`. I want the parameters to be passed in a different way, which is the `second`. `third` is what I am gonna do with the connection. I want `third` to be called like a normal function, and it also handles the opening and closing connection using a decorator. Sorry if decorator should not be used this way, but I really want to practice using it.

---Update---

What I want to achieve is basically the following:

```
def context_manager(username='user', password='password'):
    conn = OpenConnection()
    func(conn)
    CloseConnection()

def context_manager2(d={'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'}):
    content_manager(username=d['username'], password=d['password'])

# @context_manager
# @context_manager('username', '123456')
# @context_manager2
# @context_manager2(d={'username': 'username', 'password': '123456'})
def execute(conn):
    pass
```

I want to make any of the four decorators possible and still be able to call `execute` in a way like `execute()`

Comment: It's not about how to modify code, it's about how decorators work. `@decorator def function():...` is the same as `function = decorator(function)`, so `decorator` must accept a function. Moreover, what's `func` in `second`? This name isn't defined.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you give an example output?

Comment: @ForceBru Sorry for any confusion. I am taking some random attempts to make things work...I forgot to delete it.

Comment: @AdamSmith I am sorry. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you maybe just need a primer on what a decorator is. A decorator is a function that accepts a function as its only argument, and returns a function in its place. They often take the form of:

```py
def decorator(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        # it's important to accept any arguments to wrapped, thus *args and **kwargs
        # because then you can wrap _any_ function and simply pass its arguments on.
        print("Inside the wrapped function")

        retval = f(*args, **kwargs)  # pass the arguments through to the decorated function

        print("Exiting the wrapped function")

        return retval

    return wrapped
```

This lets you do something like:

```py
@decorator
def my_increment(x):
    print("Calculating...")
    return x + 1

# actually equivalent to
def my_increment(x):
    print("Calculating...")
    return x + 1

my_increment = decorator(my_increment)
```

and expect results like:

```py
>>> print(my_increment(3))
Inside the wrapped function
Calculating...
Exiting the wrapped function
4
```

Notably: `my_increment` *becomes* the decorated function at runtime, *not* at call time. You can't call `my_increment` without the decorator functionality.

---

What you're attempting to do doesn't look anything like what you'd use a decorator for. This looks like function chaining to me.

```py
def first(x=1):
    return [x]

def second(d=None):
    if d is None:
        d = {'x':10}  # why do this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3058609
    return first(d['x'])

def third(lst):
    return lst + [-1]
```

and call it like:

```py
# With @first,
# I am expecting to get [1, -1].
third(first())  # [1, -1]

# With @first(x=10),
# I am expecting to get [10, -1].
third(first(10))  # [10, -1]

# With @second,
# I am expecting to get [10, -1].
third(second())  # [10, -1]

# With @second({x:100}),
# I am expecting to get [100, -1].
third(second({'x':100}))  # [100, -1]
```

---

Note also that decorators can take parameters, but then you're talking about (bear with me...) a function that takes parameters that *returns* a function which takes a function and returns a function. You're just abstracting one more layer. Imagine:

```py
def decorator_abstracted(msg):
    """Takes a message and returns a decorator"""

    # the below is almost the exact same code as my first example
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print(msg)
            retval = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print("exiting " + msg)
            return retval

        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Now your code could be

```py
@decorator_abstracted("a decorator around my_increment")
def my_increment(x):
    print('Calculating...')
    return x + 1
```

Comment: The reason why it doesn't look like a decorator is that I am abstracting my problem. My real problem is that I want a decorator that handles open and close connection for me so that I only need to write code for handling the connection. And the connection needs parameters, which is `first`.  I want the parameters to be passed in a different way, which is the `second`. `third` is what I am gonna do with the connection. I want it to be called like a normal function and it can also handles the opening and closing connection with a decorator. Sorry if decorator should not be used this way.

Comment: @SeakyLuo that sounds like a context manager instead, though it could be a context manager used inside the decorator's wrapping method, perhaps?

Comment: Yes I am trying to implement a context manager inside a decorator. I am not sure if my case needs a decorator but I really want to practice it.

Comment: @SeakyLuo I added an example of a decorator function that takes an argument. They're one step further abstracted (and you can go arbitrarily deep, but, you know... *don't* ), but otherwise no more complex.

Comment: Where is `f` defined in the `decorator_abstracted`? I used `func` in my `first` because I saw some answers are doing it but I don't get it honestly... I previously put it in the arguments of `first`, but that seems to make using parameters impossible.

Comment: @SeakyLuo `f` is the argument to `decorator` inside `decorator_abstracted`. A decorator that accepts arguments is just a function that returns a decorator!

Comment: But I am getting an error for that `func`. I want to simply call `third()` but with `func` that seems not possible?

Comment: `@decorator_abstracted` is not a valid decorator, though `@decorator_abstracted()` may be. Is that the problem in your code? It's still very unclear what you're trying to accomplish and what errors you're receiving while trying to get there.

Comment: @SeakyLuo you're not trying to apply _multiple_ decorators, right?

Comment: No. Just one. But all four decorator calls should be valid.

Comment: Thank you. It's working! Can you take a look at my further question under your gitlab?